# SMS opt-out using mobile connect import activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, mobileconnect, data-import, unsubscribe

We are using a mobileconnect data import activity in automation studio in order to opt-out contacts orignited from another external marketing platform.

We have noticed that after importing those contacts the mobile connect demographic attribute 'status' is set to 'Inactive'.  In addition, the selected keyword subscription during import is set to 'not opted-in'.

What we would like to acheive is to change only the subscription staus to 'not opted-in' for a specifc keyword and keep the mobile connect demographic field 'status' to be 'Active'. (The reason is we would like in the future to target those contacts with a new keyword. We found 'Inactive' status prevents sending for all keywords). **Is there a known posbbile way to acheive that by using the mobile connect import activity?**

Many thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 0):

The last part on this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312828&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 might be helpful. It mentions that you need to import the contacts twice.